# Discord.js How do i check if a channel is available to everyone

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to check if a channel is available (at least to view) to everyone, is there a way to do this?

I've been looking around for a while now and cannot find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`GuildChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel) has a [`permissionsFor()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=permissionsFor) method, which can be used to check the permissions of a user/role in the channel.
To check permissions for `@everyone`, access the [`RoleManager.everyone`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=everyone) property. ([`guild.roles.everyone`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles)):

```js
// This example assumes that the channel is a guild channel.
client.on("message", (message) => {

  const channel = message.channel,
    guild = channel.guild,
    everyone = guild.roles.everyone;

  // see: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS
  if (channel.permissionsFor(everyone).has("VIEW_CHANNEL")) {
    console.log("@everyone can view channel!");
  } else {
    console.log("@everyone cannot view channel!");
  }

});
```